# sql: status not later than a parameter @date

Tags: sql, t-sql

q1: given a table : ID, Date, Status. Write a SQL query which receives @ID @Date and retrieve the status the person with that id on that date or the last status not later than that @date if that date doesn't exist.

I have tried to write queries for above questions. I would appreciate you remarks:

```
SELECT TOP (1) status from MyTable AS T
WHERE T.Date <= @date && T.id = @id
ORDER BY T.Date
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `AND` instead of `&&`, and order by date descending:

```
SELECT TOP 1 status 
from MyTable AS T 
WHERE T.Date <= @date 
    and T.id = @id 
ORDER BY T.Date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 status from MyTable AS T WHERE T.Date <= @date AND T.id = @id ORDER BY T.Date